# Android: controlling the ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like it than when I click something on the ListView that the text box won't appear.
For example : [in this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) pat 6 : when "American Samoa" was clicked appeared a text box on the buttom of the screen with the text "sa".

Comment: what are you trying? what error you get?

Comment: @user370305 - not sure what to do... I don't get errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove this line from onItemClick()**,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: +1 and @Belgi: For your knowledge  it is not TextBox, it is called [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) in Android.